# Jenkins User Not Accessible In Bash and Builds Not Working

Tags: bash, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I am trying to become a Jenkins user through this command - `sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins`.

When I do run it, this happens in my shell: `bash-4.2$ Killed`.

I have been trying to debug it by identifying the memory allocation used on the server (we have plenty), reading debug lines of processes being killed, and the jenkins log but there's nothing that leads me towards a solution.

How do I start to debug this problem and what could be going on? There aren't any obvious errors being thrown my way.

I've discovered that when I restart the server, I can log in as the jenkins user and the jenkins builds work. However, shortly thereafter, I cannot log in and the builds no longer work.

Comment: This is a guess. does the jenkins user have a shell defined? Maybe it does not have permission to run a shell.

Comment: @Mamun it does not have a shell defined in /etc/passwd if that's what you're asking. It is the standard /bin/false. We tried /bin/bash as well with no luck.

Comment: dang it. I thought I was onto something. evidently not.